PDA takes ~10s to upate even after tx is confirmed
I have been using anchor programs before , In those programs i could send multiple transactions back to back and the pda are reflected correct in every transactions.
But since then i started creating solana native programs, And there I noticed i have to wait approx 10s after the tx is succesfull otherwise  the pda won't reflect data from the previous transaction.
I'm not reading the data in JS, The program is trying to read the data, the the state is not updated yet for some reasons
It creates some weird race conditions , which should happen, Since i'm transaction are sent one by one rather then simultaneously.
I tried this in local-validator as well, same thing happens there as well. But i haven't faced this situation in anchor programs
Could it be Tha i'm doing something wrong, or is it common occurunce?

There is not really a difference in how PDAs change between anchor and native. Once the transaction is done the values are updated in the validators. What i suspect is happening is that you are requesting the PDA data with a 'finalized' confirmation flag. This one would not get you the new value until the transaction is finalized. If you use getAccountInfo to get the data you can probably just set it to confirmed as second parameter.
Best check your whole code that you are requesting the blockhash confirmed, confirm the transaction and then get the new data with that commitment level.
You can read about this here:
https://docs.solanalabs.com/de/consensus/commitments#:~:text=There%20are%20three%20specific%20commitment,Finalized

PDA data is read in the program itself i'm not fetching the data in Js, still the State in the pda is not updated, why is that? I tried this in my local validator, tried to send two transaction 1 after the another still the issue

How do you get the blockhash for your transaction in anchor and how when you call the native program?

Are you requesting a new block hash between the transactions?

yes, new blockhash every transactions.The problem is the data onchain is not updated ,so it cause in instruction execution
